# AC with bed frame in front of it

Tags: air-conditioning

I haven't installed it yet, but i got an AC unit for my window and it doesn't fit in the window i intended to install it in. It will fit in my other window but then my wooden slated bed frame will be pushed up against it. How deleterious will this be? Is it okay short term for no more than 4 days? What are the dangers, if any?

Comment: Measure tbe original window, find and purchase an AC that will fit then return the other one. Avoids all issues.

Comment: ...so don't push the bed frame up against it...

Answer (score 1):

As long as it's not blocking the air flow, the AC unit will be fine. It probably won't cool down the room as well due to the circulation being compromised by the obstruction of the bed.